# Check for Component Prop in Styled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-component

I have a component that accepts a prop that runs another component.  It looks like this:

```
const IconBase = styled.div`
  // Css Styles Go Here
`;

const Icon = props => (
  <IconBase>
    <props.name />
  </IconBase>
);
```

This component works as follows:  `<Icon name={Facebook} />` -- which is basically equivalent to the following:

```
<Icon><Facebook /></Icon>
```

The `<Facebook />` component comes from `react-icons`.

Now, this all works as I wish.  What I want to do now is run a check in `Styled-Components` for the name prop and then output the appropriate background color.  Something like this:

```
${props => props.name === "Facebook" && `background-color: #3b5998`}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to do the conditional check in `Styled-Components`.  Checking for `Facebook` won't work -- as I'm not passing a String to the `name` component.  What then, should I check for?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
const mapBackgroundStyle = {
    'facebook': 'background-color: #3b5998'
};

const Button = styled.button`
  background: ${props => mapBackgroundStyle[props.name]};
`;
```

you could also used a function instead of an object mapping.

Comment: Doesn't that just run into the same problem I'm already having -- namely, that I don't know what value `props.name` is returning?

Comment: you could just pass an additional prop <prop.name type="facebook" />. Also, you could use React.createElement, and use props.name to create the component and pass in props that way.. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out.  This is the check that works:

`${props => props.name === Facebook ...`

Here is why that works...

When I have the following component: `<Icon name={Facebook} />`, the prop value `{Facebook}` is a function with the name of Facebook. So that is what I need to check for, a function with a particular function name. So, all I have to do is leave off the quotes and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary condition in styled-components this way:

const Button = styled.button
  `background: ${props => props.name === 'Facebook' ? '#3b5998' : 'white'};`
;